# How do I install plpython on MacOs X 10.5?

Tags: python, macos, postgresql

I have just installed PostgreSQL 8.3.4 on Mac OS X 10.5 (using ports), but I cannot figure out how to enable PL/Python. When I run the `CREATE LANGUAGE plpythonu` I get the following errors:

```
ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/plpython": No such file or directory
STATEMENT:  CREATE LANGUAGE plpythonu;
psql:<stdin>:18: ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/plpython": No such file or directory
```

How can I fix it? Ideally I would prefer to avoid compiling Postgres without `port` or something like that.

Thia the output of running pg_config:

```
BINDIR = /opt/local/lib/postgresql83/bin
DOCDIR = 
INCLUDEDIR = /opt/local/include/postgresql83
PKGINCLUDEDIR = /opt/local/include/postgresql83
INCLUDEDIR-SERVER = /opt/local/include/postgresql83/server
LIBDIR = /opt/local/lib/postgresql83
PKGLIBDIR = /opt/local/lib/postgresql83
LOCALEDIR = 
MANDIR = /opt/local/share/man
SHAREDIR = /opt/local/share/postgresql83
SYSCONFDIR = /opt/local/etc/postgresql83
PGXS = /opt/local/lib/postgresql83/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk
CONFIGURE = '--prefix=/opt/local' '--sysconfdir=/opt/local/etc/postgresql83' '--bindir=/opt/local/lib/postgresql83/bin' '--libdir=/opt/local/lib/postgresql83' '--includedir=/opt/local/include/postgresql83' '--datadir=/opt/local/share/postgresql83' '--mandir=/opt/local/share/man' '--without-docdir' '--with-includes=/opt/local/include' '--with-libraries=/opt/local/lib' '--with-openssl' '--with-bonjour' '--with-readline' '--with-zlib' '--with-libxml' '--with-libxslt' '--enable-thread-safety' '--enable-integer-datetimes' '--with-ossp-uuid' 'CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.0' 'CFLAGS=-O2' 'CPPFLAGS=-I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include/ossp' 'CPP=/usr/bin/cpp-4.0' 'LDFLAGS=-L/opt/local/lib'
CC = /usr/bin/gcc-4.0 -no-cpp-precomp
CPPFLAGS = -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include/ossp -I/opt/local/include/libxml2 -I/opt/local/include
CFLAGS = -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Winline -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv
CFLAGS_SL = 
LDFLAGS = -L/opt/local/lib -L/opt/local/lib -L/opt/local/lib
LDFLAGS_SL = 
LIBS = -lpgport -lxslt -lxml2 -lssl -lcrypto -lz -lreadline -lm 
VERSION = PostgreSQL 8.3.4
```

(I've just switched from Linux to Mac a couple of days ago... In Ubuntu stuff like that used to *just work*, so I am pretty lost.)

Comment: Please accept your own answer so that (1) it's obvious what the helpful answer is and (2) no one else spends a lot of time answering this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silly me:

```
[lib/postgresql83] > variants postgresql83
 postgresql83 has the variants:
    universal
    python: add support for python
    krb5: add support for Kerberos 5 authentication
    perl: add Perl support
```

(I'd had `universal`.)

This means that you have to install the right variant of PostgreSQL to make your python functions fly.

```
$ sudo port install postgresql83 +python postgresql-server +python
```